# in order traversal iterative binary search tree

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, stack

I have defined pre order like this:

```
void pre_order(binary_tree_t* root) { //D<root>L<left>R<right>
  if (root) {
    printf("%d ", root->data);
    pre_order(root->left);
    pre_order(root->right);
  }
}
```

and found difficulty to do the iterative one:

```
void in_order(binary_tree_t* root) { //L<left>D<root>R<right> -- inorder -- gives sorted list
  if (root) {
    in_order(root->left);
    display_element(root->data);
    in_order(root->right);
  }
}
void iter_in_order(binary_tree_t* root) {//L<left>D<root>R<right>
  stack_t *s = create_stack(size_binary_tree(root)+1)
  push(s, root)
  while (!is_empty_stack(s)) {
    push(s, root->left);
    root = pop(s);
    display_element(root->data);
    push(s, root->right);
  }
}
```

Can you help please articulate how this might be done?

Comment: Don't forget to destroy the stack. Also it would be nice if `iter_in_order` did nothing if its parameter is null.

Answer (score 1):

When you start the traversal, you should first push all nodes on the path to the left-most node -- as that is the one you want to output first. Inside the loop you immediately start with popping a node and printing it. Then, only push the right child when that child exists. And if it exists, deal with it just like at the very start: traverse to its left-most decendent and push those nodes as well.

Here is your updated code:

```
void iter_in_order(binary_tree_t* root) {
  stack_t *s = create_stack(size_binary_tree(root)+1);
  push(s, root);
  while (root->left) push(s, root = root->left);
  while (!is_empty_stack(s)) {
    root = pop(s);
    display_element(root->data);
    if (root->right) {
      push(s, root = root->right);
      while (root->left) push(s, root = root->left);
    }
  }
}
```